# Copy Image to local storage using rn-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I am using react-native-image-picker to get image from the system. As soon as the user selects and image, i am dispatching an redux action and it looks like this.

**imgSrc** variable contains image URI. I used split and pop to get the image name.
But still the image has not been copied from imgSrc to my new generated path.

```
export const addPlace = (title , address , imgSrc) =>{
    return async dispatch => {
        const fileName = imgSrc.split('/').pop()
        const newPath = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/' + fileName

        try{
            await RNFetchBlob.fs.cp( imgSrc , newPath)
        } catch ( err){
            console.log('error')
            throw err
        }

        dispatch({
            type : ADD_PLACE ,
            placeData : {
                title : title,
                address : address,
                src : newPath
            }
        })
    }
}
```